# query generated by LINQ removes where clause

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4

I am generating a simple query using LINQ. 
My model is

```
public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeId {get; set;}
    public string FirstName {get; set;}        
    [Required]
    public string LastName {get; set;}
}
```

My LINQ query is

```
var q = db.Employees.Where (i => i.LastName != null);
```

This query is translated into the following SQL (see there is no `where` clause)

```sql
SELECT 
[Extent1].[EmployeeId ] AS [EmployeeId], 
[Extent1].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], 
[Extent1].[LastName] AS [LastName]
FROM [dbo].[Employees] AS [Extent1]
```

If I remove the `Required` attribute from my model, the SQL query adds the `Where` clause. So, I'am assuming that LINQ optimizes the query by removing the where clause. But I want to keep the `Required` attribute and want to use LINQ. Is there any work around?

Since I am working on Old database, I have some records where `LastName` is null. But I want to add `Required` field so that all new records will have values for `LastName`.

Comment: So you want your _model_ to require a `LastName` but the _database_ does not?

Comment: @DStanley Yes, you are Right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using code-first to generate your database.  What seems to be happening is you're adding a `IS NOT NULL` condition against a DB column that is not nullable, which EF appears to be optimizing away.

If the DB column is not nullable, then having an `IS NOT NULL` `WHERE` clause makes no sense.

If your DB column is nullable, but you want the *model* to require a value, then you may need to add another layer to separate your domain model from your database schema.  EF is meant to model your data schema as closely as possible.  If you want to apply business rules that differ from your data constraints, you may need to to that in your ViewModel (or whatever is appropriate for your architecture).